# WPF Application MVVM - Using OneWay binding on Textbox, Property becomes null after getting data again

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have an WPF application using MVVM.

I have a DataGrid bound to an ObservableCollection and a TextBox bound to the DataGrid SelectedItem, so when I click an item in the DataGrid, the TextBox is populated.

I also have a Button using Command and CommandParameter and using RelayCommand to check if the TextBox is empty and then disabling the Button.

That all works great, if I use UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged. The thing I don't like is because of the binding, if the user changes the text in the TextBox, the DataGrid record is edited. If the user then changes their mind about changing the record, and clicks somewhere else, the record in the DataGrid still shows the edited text.

What I have tried is using Mode=OneWay on the TextBox binding, which works in that it doesn't update the DataGrid record. After the data is saved to the database, I need to manually refresh the DataGrid to show the changes.

The code I have in my code behind is the DataGrid's SelectionChanged event which sets a property on the ViewModel to the selected item.

So in order to show the new changes, I thought adding a call to my GetCategories again after the changes would work. However when the code executes OnPropertyChanged("ReceivedCategories"), my CurrentCategory property becomes null.

My code:

CategoryModel.cs

```
public class CategoryModel
{
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    readonly SalesLinkerDataContext _dbContext = new SalesLinkerDataContext();

    public ObservableCollection<CategoryModel> GetCategories() 
    {
       var result = _dbContext.tblSalesCategories.ToList();

       List<CategoryModel> categoriesList = result.Select(item => new CategoryModel
       {
           CategoryID = item.CategoryID, 
           Description = item.Description.Trim()
       }).ToList();


        return new ObservableCollection<CategoryModel>(categoriesList);
    }

    internal bool UpdateCategory(int id, string description)
    {
        if (_dbContext.tblSalesCategories.Any(x => x.Description == description))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("A category with the same name already exists.");
            return false;
        }

        try
        {
            var category = (from a in _dbContext.tblSalesCategories
                where a.CategoryID == id
                select a).FirstOrDefault();


            if (category != null)
            {
                category.Description = description;
                _dbContext.SubmitChanges();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    internal bool AddCategory(string description)
    {
        if (_dbContext.tblSalesCategories.Any(x => x.Description == description))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("A category with the same name already exists.");
            return false;
        }

        var newCategory = new tblSalesCategory();
        newCategory.Description = description;

        try
        {
            _dbContext.tblSalesCategories.InsertOnSubmit(newCategory);
            _dbContext.SubmitChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            return false;
        }

        return true;



    }

    internal bool DeleteCategory(int id)
    {
        var result = _dbContext.tblSalesCategories.FirstOrDefault(x => x.CategoryID == id);

        try
        {
            if (result != null)
            {
                _dbContext.tblSalesCategories.DeleteOnSubmit(result);
                _dbContext.SubmitChanges();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

CategoriesViewModel.cs

```
public class CategoriesViewModel : ViewModelBase, IPageViewModel
{        
    public CategoryModel CurrentCategory = new CategoryModel();

    public ObservableCollection<CategoryModel> Categories = new ObservableCollection<CategoryModel>(); 

    public RelayCommand GetCategoriesRelay;
    public RelayCommand UpdateCategoryRelay;
    public RelayCommand AddCategoryRelay;
    public RelayCommand DeleteCategoryRelay;

    #region Get Categories Command
    public ICommand GetCategoriesCommand
    {
        get
        {
            GetCategoriesRelay = new RelayCommand(p => GetCategories(),
            p => CanGetCategories());

            return GetCategoriesRelay;
        }
    }

    private bool CanGetCategories()
    {
        return true;
    }

    private void GetCategories()
    {
        Categories = CurrentCategory.GetCategories();
        ReceivedCategories = Categories;
    }
    #endregion

    #region Update Category Command
    public ICommand UpdateCategoryCommand
    {
        get
        {
            UpdateCategoryRelay = new RelayCommand(p => UpdateCategory((string) p),
                p => CanUpdateCategory());

            return UpdateCategoryRelay;
        }
    }

    public bool CanUpdateCategory()
    {
        return !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Description);
    }

    public void UpdateCategory(string description)
    {
        if (CurrentCategory.UpdateCategory(CurrentCategory.CategoryID, description))
        {
            GetCategories();
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Add Category Command
    public ICommand AddCategoryCommand
    {
        get
        {
            AddCategoryRelay = new RelayCommand(p => AddCategory((string) p),
                p => CanAddCategory());

            return AddCategoryRelay;
        }
    }


    private bool CanAddCategory()
    {
        return !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Description);
    }

    private void AddCategory(string description)
    {
        if (CurrentCategory.AddCategory(description))
            GetCategories();
    }

    #endregion

    #region Delete Category Command

    public ICommand DeleteCategoryCommand
    {
        get
        {
            DeleteCategoryRelay = new RelayCommand(p => DeleteCategory((int) p),
                p => CanDeleteCategory());

            return DeleteCategoryRelay;
        }
    }

    private bool CanDeleteCategory()
    {
        return true;
    }

    private void DeleteCategory(int id)
    {
        if (CurrentCategory.DeleteCategory(id))
            GetCategories();
    }

    #endregion



    /// <summary>
    /// Describes the name that will be used for the menu option
    /// </summary>
    public string Name
    {
        get { return "Manage Categories"; }  

    }

    public string Description
    {
        get
        { 
            return CurrentCategory.Description;      
        }
        set
        {
            CurrentCategory.Description = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Description");
        }
    }


    public ObservableCollection<CategoryModel> ReceivedCategories
    {
        get { return Categories; }

        set
        {
            Categories = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ReceivedCategories");
        }
    }
}
```

CategoryView.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="SalesLinker.CategoriesView"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
  xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"      
  mc:Ignorable="d" 
  d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="600" Background="White">

<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding GetCategoriesCommand}" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>

<Grid >
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="45"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="250"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Margin="20,0,0,0" FontSize="20" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Content="Categories"/>

    <DataGrid x:Name="LstCategories" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"  AutoGenerateColumns="false"  

              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ReceivedCategories, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectionChanged="Selector_OnSelectionChanged"
              HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" GridLinesVisibility="None"
              CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" CanUserSortColumns="True" Background="White">     
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding  Path=Description}" IsReadOnly="True" Header="Description" Width="300" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>

    <Button Command="{Binding AddCategoryCommand}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="50" Width="50" Margin="0,20,0,0" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="Transparent"
            CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=TbDescription, Path=Text}">
        <Image Source="/Images/Plus.png"/>
    </Button>

    <Button Command="{Binding DeleteCategoryCommand}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="50" Width="50" Margin="0,75,0,0" Background="Transparent"  BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="Transparent"
              CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem.CategoryID, ElementName=LstCategories, Mode=OneWay }">
        <Image Source="/Images/Minus.png"/>
    </Button>


    <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="75"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Label VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Content="Description:"/>

        <TextBox x:Name="TbDescription" DataContext="CategoryModel" Grid.Row="0" 
                 Grid.Column="1" Width="250" Height="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                 HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,0,0,0"
                 Text="{Binding SelectedItem.Description, ElementName=LstCategories, Mode=OneWay}"/>

        <Button   Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,0,0,0" 
                  Height="20" Width="120" Content="Update Description" 

                  Command="{Binding UpdateCategoryCommand}"
                  CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=TbDescription, Path=Text}" />
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

And I have also just noticed that using Mode=OneWay on the TextBox breaks my CanExecute pieces of code as well.

So all I can think of is either:

1. Find a way to bind another property to the TextBox as well?
2. Find a way of using UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged on the TextBox, but prevent the DataGrid being updated.

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I couldn't get the above suggestion by SeeuD1 to work, but have have figured out what the problem was.

I have The DataGrid's ItemsSource bound to ReceivedCategories and in the code behind, the SelectionChanged event to use to bind to the TextBox.

After the database save, I call my GetCategories() again to refresh the data.

So when ReceivedCategories gets the data again, the DataGrid's ItemsSource is updated, but not before the SelectionChange event fires trying to set my CurrentCategory to the SelectedItem. However there is no longer anything selected in the DataGrid (index is -1), so assignment fails and sets CurrentCategory to null.

Fix is to simply only assign CurrentCategory to the SelectedItem if something is selected.

Old code:

```
private void Selector_OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var viewmodel = (CategoriesViewModel)DataContext;
        viewmodel.CurrentCategory = LstCategories.SelectedItems.Cast<CategoryModel>().FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

Fixed:

```
private void Selector_OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var viewmodel = (CategoriesViewModel)DataContext;

        if (LstCategories.SelectedIndex > -1)
            viewmodel.CurrentCategory = LstCategories.SelectedItems.Cast<CategoryModel>().FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

For the null value in the Observable List you have to update the list with a copy of it and an Dispatcher.Invoke otherwise the gui will crash or show null I had a similar problem on update a observable list in a thread.

So you should write your changes in a list like:

```
//Your Copy List
ObservableCollection<CategoryModel> _ReceivedCategories;
//Your Execute command for the Gui
public void onUpdateExecuted(object parameter){
Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => ReceivedCategories = new ObservableCollection <CategoryModel> (_ReceivedCategories));
}

//Your Undo Command if the Inputs are not ok
public void onUndoExecuted(object parameter){
Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => _ReceivedCategories = new ObservableCollection <CategoryModel> (ReceivedCategories));
}

//Your Command on every input which is set
public void onInputExecuted(object parameter){
_ReceivedCategories.add(Your Object);
}
```

And you can add an update Command for the Main List so you first update the Copy List with the values and after an Command set the Copy Collection in the Main Collection

Hope that helps

Comment: Hi, Sorry I am confused as to where to put this code?

Comment: First you have to set an new ObservableCollection like _ReceivedCategories. This is your List with the actual values. This List is updated every Time. And if the user is set an update command like clicking an button or something else the update command has the Dispatcher.Invoke in it. And an other Command Like Click on the ui or smething else has an ReverseCommand and Copy the ReceivedCategories  in the _ReceivedCategories. I Edited the Code

Comment: Was still getting the null problem, but see my answer below. The Invoke would still not have worked as the problem was being caused somewhere else.